# want to use javascript functions while they are within window.onload

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, console

The `addEventListener` doesn't add events, I found that I should use

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // whole code here
}
```

but, when I try to use the functions that are within the `window.onload` in the browser console, I can not, only the outer functions of it could be, I want to use them even if they were in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly assign the functions to the window inside the handler.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  window.someFn = () => {
    // ...
  };
  someFn();
  // you can also use someFn in the browser console
});
```