# want to use functions within ready jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, browser, console

I have a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68779789/want-to-use-javascript-functions-while-they-are-within-window-onload), my question was about how to access all the *JavaScript* functions in the web browser console even if they were within `window.onload = function() {// code and functions}`  , but this time I want to do the same thing with *jQuery*:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // I want to access all the functions that are here in the web console
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same syntax as in your previous question. Simply assign the function to the `window`.

The following example illustrates what I mean. Note that you do not need the `setTimeout()`, this is just for this example here to auto-execute the `your_function()` when it is defined.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.your_function = function(){
    console.log("your function");
  };
  your_function();
});

// setTimeout() is needed because the $.ready() function was not executed when 
// this code block is reached, the function(){your_function();} is needed because
// the your_function() is not defined when the code is reached
setTimeout(function(){
  your_function();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note 2: I suggenst not to define global functions in the `$(document).ready()` if there is not a good reason for it. You can define the functions outside and then call them in the `$(document).ready()`.